# Jquery .jstree() method is not recognized

Tags: jquery, jstree

http://embed.plnkr.co/EUqKQbJC1zIKKZzoK61Q/preview

This is the plunker id. I am not able to see the jstree. I used the example code from the jstree website. Pls help.

Comment: also include the important code (HTML Markup, Header Section) in your SO-question

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add the Stylesheet right?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
```

Add this to your header right after the jstree.js file.

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jstree.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.jstree.com/3.2.0/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://static.jstree.com/3.2.0/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
```